# MongoDB GridFS Embedding Images (PHP/HTML)

Tags: php, html, mongodb, image, nosql

I am using MongoDB and GridFS, but I'd like to be able to include it within an image tag on a page called display, getimage.php being the page that got the image from Mongo, such as `<img src='getimage.php' height='100px' width='100px'>`

Would this be possible and if so what would be the implimentation for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only using `getimage.php` will be not enough. You should also provide an identifier for the image you want to retrieve. This way, you can use this technique for an unlimited number of images.

```
<img src='getimage.php?oid=4rf55...' height='100px' width='100px'>
```

If you use the files OID, you can easily get the image from GridFS. In `getimage.php` you simply get the image based on the value provided with the `oid=....`param `$oid = $_GET['oid']`.